# tsql - match up to closest number in lookup

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, lookup

I have a select which returns a duration value.  what i would like to do is look up this value in a lookup table and return a value for yield which is closest to this duration value.

e.g

i have a duration of 0.20 for USD so from my look up table below which is derived from this code:

```
select fld1_val, mrkt_cap_wght from dw_iss_indx_cnstnt AS ai WITH (NOLOCK)

INNER JOIN  dw_issue_dg AS i WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON ai.indx_instr_id = i.instr_id 
  AND ai.as_of_dte > getdate()-2

INNER JOIN dw_issue_alt_id AS ia WITH (NOLOCK)
  on ia.instr_id = ai.indx_instr_id
  AND id_ctxt_typ = 'Bloomberg ID'
  AND denom_curr_cde = 'USD'
```

this returns:

```
fld1_val    mrkt_cap_wght
0.08        5.0168
0.25        5.03
0.5         5.09
1           5.21
2           5.2
5           5.51
10          5.67
12          5.69
15          5.7
20          5.71
```

So what i would do is lookup against this and because 0.20 is closest to 0.25 i would return 5.03 as my yield.

However i am unsure of how to do this as the look up is not looking for an exact match, just a closest to value.  Any idea how i could do this?

Comment: Does `select top 1` and `order by abs( col - value )` point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Dur decimal(5,2)=0.20;

select TOP 1 fld1_val, mrkt_cap_wght from dw_iss_indx_cnstnt AS ai WITH (NOLOCK)

INNER JOIN  dw_issue_dg AS i WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON ai.indx_instr_id = i.instr_id 
  AND ai.as_of_dte > getdate()-2

INNER JOIN dw_issue_alt_id AS ia WITH (NOLOCK)
  on ia.instr_id = ai.indx_instr_id
  AND id_ctxt_typ = 'Bloomberg ID'
  AND denom_curr_cde = 'USD'
ORDER BY ABS(@Dur-fld1_val)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i put this into a temporary table and then cross applied with my worktable to drop in the figures i required.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test/verify this right now, but it seems like you could use `min` or an order by with selecting the top 1 against the absolute difference between the given value and the table value.

Answer (score 0):

One quick-and-dirty way to do this:

```
SELECT fld1_val
FROM table
WHERE (abs(mrkt_cap_wght - 0.25)) = (SELECT MIN(abs(mrkt_cap_wght - 0.25)) FROM table);
```

I've tested it on a different table and it definitely works, but it admittedly feels a little clumsy.